# Phonegap/Cordova deviceready or requestFileSystem not working android

Tags: android, cordova

Cordova 3.1.0
S3 Android 4.2 and Nexus 4 Android 4.4

I am seeing rather odd behavior from the cordova library. Include an init file in the root html file of my project. Every thing seems to be loading and working fine however, when I use `window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, setFS, fail);`

It doesn't seem to work on the first try.

```
console.log("Loaded INIT");
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceIsReady, false);

    function setFS(fileSystem){
        window.rootFS = fileSystem.root;
        console.log("FS SET");
    }
    function fail(error){
        console.log(error);
    }
    function deviceIsReady() {
        window.requestFileSystem  = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
        //window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, setFS, fail);
        var attempts = 0;

        var intervalID = window.setInterval(function(){
            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, setFS, fail);
            console.log("Requested fileSystem");
            attempts++;
            if(window.rootFS || attempts>3)
                clearInterval(intervalID);
        },500);


        console.log("INIT_________");

    }
```

The above code produces the following output when the app is started.

```
"Requested fileSystem"
"FS SET"
"Requested fileSystem"
"INIT_________"
"Loaded INIT"
```

This was the hacky workaround that I had to implement in order to get the fileSystem.root. Now deviceIsReady is being called both times which leads me to believe that the "deviceready" event is working. As you can see setFS is only being called once - the second time. I see similar behavior when I programmatically call window.requestFileSystem via an onclick handler of an input button. On the first click "setFS" is not called but the second time that I click the button it works fine. In addition this interval was originally a do while loop that exited when the same conditions were met. I had the exact same results. It would exit on second time through.

Finally, I see the similar behavior when trying to use fileTransfer.download. I have to loop through twice in order for it to work. Now I can't push this to production! Someone please help!

Answer (score 1):

I tried your example and it worked as expected on my N4 running 4.4.

You are checking for `window.rootFS` right after the call to requestFileSystem, which is a little suspect. The setFS callback will be called asynchronously, so there is no chance of it ever being set where you check it.